# Unity отложенное выполнение

Tags: c#, многопоточность, unity3d

Делаю свою кастомную таблицу. То есть UI элемент. Есть метод drawAxis, который рисует сетку. В нём происходят все вычисления. Поскольку из потока графики нельзя создавать и удалять объекты, для текстовых элементов запускаю Corotine. Проблема в том, что после окончания Corotine мне нужно отрисовать по расчётным значениям линию. Причём необходимо это сделать в графическом потоке.
Собственно вопрос. Как на С# реализовать ожидание завершения расчётов?

```
    protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)
{
    vh.Clear();
    this.vh = vh;
    DrawAxis(vh);
 // метод необходимо запустить после полного выполнения    
    DrawLine(vh);
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, корутина запускается в методе `DrawAxis(vh);` и после того, как она отработала требуется выполнить метод `DrawLine(vh);` верно?

Comment: @Pollux да, верно, проблема в том, что я не могу вклиниться в тот же поток графики

Comment: А если `DrawLine(vh);` запускать непосредственно из той корутины. Тогда не потребуется реализация ожидания.

Comment: @Pollux В Corotine нельзя рисовать графику, как я понял

Comment: ну еще как вариант можно объявить `bool` переменную, когда расчеты выполнятся переводить её в `true`, а в месте, где требуется ожидание поставить цикл `while(!check)`. Но тогда на время расчетов может повиснуть главный поток, поэтому не лучший вариант, очень костыльно.

Comment: @RodGers а почему в корутине нельзя рисовать графику? она ведь выполняется не в отдельном потоке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вы [делаете графику так](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.html):

```
public class Image : Graphic
{
   protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)
  { 
  }
}
```

И вы потом вызываете метод `OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)` ? Если так? Ну сделайте два класса наследника
 ImageFirst : Graphic и ImageSecond : Graphic, а в каждом свой метод и запускайте их тогда, когда надо, когда другие расчеты закончатся.

```
public class ImageFirst : Graphic
{
  protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)
{
    vh.Clear();
    this.vh = vh;
    DrawAxis(vh);
}
```

и

```
public class ImageSecond : Graphic
{
   protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)
    {
      DrawLine(vh);
    }
}
```

Comment: Решил немного по другому, но этот вариант тоже подходит